# SSH session via Apache web page on ports 80/443

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, firewall

I'm running a web/mail server at home, it is publicly accessible on the standard ports. I have SSH running on a non-standard port and can usually connect to this externally, but my day job has a firewall in place that is preventing me from connecting via SSH on that alternate port, even though a port scan from work shows the port is open. The firewall can tell it's SSH traffic and therefore blocks it.

I've been searching for some software that will let me have a web page on my existing server that will bring up a window and let me have a ssh session to talk to the web server itself. I'm finding a few web SSH packages out there, but these provide a new service listening on a new port, I need this to be served up from the existing web server without using a new port, so it would have to play nice with Apache. I'm only needing it to talk to one specific system, in this case localhost.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a good question, but belongs on Software Recommendations SE.  Please post there.  Thanks!

Comment: You probably want the ProxyPath directive (and its reverse)

Answer (score 1):

> my day job has a firewall in place

Depending on your workplace, this may range from "just talk to your IT staff to get an exception" all the way to "attempting to bypass firewall policy gets you fired". Proceed with caution.

Especially if it's a DPI firewall that detects traffic by content, I'd lean towards it being the latter.

> that is preventing me from connecting via SSH on that alternate port, even though a port scan from work shows the port is open. The firewall can tell it's SSH traffic and therefore blocks it.

It might be enough to directly put your SSH traffic in TLS; there are several ways to do that. For example, `stunnel` (raw TLS) or using Apache as an HTTP 'CONNECT' proxy (HTTPS switching to raw TLS). The former still uses a separate port; the latter can run on the same 443 as your web vhosts.

For the first example, run stunnel on your server to set up a TLS listener that proxies connections to a local non-TLS service (sshd); socat may also work. On the client side, either set `ProxyCommand` to a command that connects to the TLS server (socat, gnutls-cli, openssl s_client), or run a similar instance of stunnel with opposite configuration.

For the second example, configure Apache httpd as a "forward" proxy (the "regular" kind of HTTP proxy, not to be confused with reverse proxying as below) that accepts CONNECT requests to localhost (be careful to not make your server an "open proxy"; enable authentication if not sure). On the client side, `proxytunnel` can be used as the ProxyCommand.

> I'm finding a few web SSH packages out there, but these provide a new service listening on a new port, I need this to be served up from the existing web server without using a new port

That's a very common way of running webapps that aren't PHO. Having a separate service on its own port allows the app service to maintain persistent state (and more importantly, persistent TCP connections) between HTTP requests.

The way you usually deploy such webapps is by putting them behind an HTTP reverse proxy (and/or load balancer), such as Nginx, Traefik, or indeed Apache httpd.

Within Apache httpd, you can use `ProxyPass` (in several different ways) to route a single vhost, or a specific URL within that vhost, to your webapp service; Apache will accept requests on its usual ports and will proxy them to the app running on localhost:23456 or whatever.